# Do questions that are no longer true still add value?

Tags: discussion

[This older post](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/112957/why-does-google-still-use-paging-instead-of-progressive-loading) came back into circulation today - it asks why Google still uses paging instead of infinite loading.

When a question is based on a fundamentally outdated premise, should it be closed? There's nothing technically wrong with it, and the archival factor is somewhat interesting ("Google used to be this way, and here are some answers why.") But since posts tend to indefinitely re-up... it could be confusing with examples that aren't as ubiquitous as Google. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The general premise is still a sound one for a question though - pagination vs infinite scroll. Sure, Google as the main example isn't as relevant today but I think it's still useful to provide context to the question.

Really, the issue is the way the question was written, rather than the example. It's more of an "X sucks, amirite?" question, so it should've been worded more directly around Infinite Scroll / Pagination in a specific situation.

Comment: In your opinion - should older posts be *edited* to become more updated or relevant?

Comment: @Izquierdo That's a bit risky because it could make any answers that were relevent at the time no longer apply to the newly-worded question. So as a rule, no, I think the original text should remain. Although an obvious "/EDIT -" appended to the question text could cover off both problems.